# JavaScript window.onload append displays UNDER body

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I have a window.onload function that creates a div and appends it to the body.

It works great and if I look at the source code I actually see

Existing ContentNew Content

However when visually looking at the page the content is being displayed UNDER the body. So its creating a second scroll bar and the regular content is under one scrollbar and the appended content is not included. If I inspect the element I can literally see it is under the body tag. So the blue part is the body tag and the white part is the appended div. Any ideas?

I also tried appending to an existing div and it showed up 9n the left side of the page, so that was also no help.

[image]

Comment: Code?..........

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've been looking at code too long today and just realized although I've been thinking appendChild the code actually said append.
So there you have it. Modified code and it now shows up as expected. ‍♀️